# set_permission_overrides not assigning permission with dpytest

Tags: python, discord.py, pytest

I am trying to configure a testing bot with dpytest. I want to create a bot which has permission to manage channels
Here is my code base:

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(params=BOT_FIXTURE)
async def bot(request) -> AsyncGenerator[Tuple[commands.Bot, str], None]:
    b = commands.Bot(
        command_prefix=settings.DISCORD_COMMAND_PREFIX,
        intents=intents,
        strip_after_prefix=True,
        help_command=None,
    )

    dpytest.configure(b)
    guild = dpytest.get_config().guilds[0]
    await dpytest.set_permission_overrides(
            target=guild.members[0], channel=guild.text_channels[0], manage_channels=True
    )
    
    # this statement returns false
    print('permissions?', guild.members[0].guild_permissions.manage_channels)
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You set a permission override for `guild.text_channels[0]`, not the guild level permission

Comment: How can I set permission override for the guild?
set_permission_overrides take channel and target as parameter

Comment: You can't, you'll need to do something like giving them a role with the permission you need. (Or if you only care about the channel this would work fine)

Comment: I tried that but I don't have the permission to manage roles as well. 
I also tried to make the member as owner of the guild. That also didn't work
Can you give an example how I can either make someone owner or assign the permissions

Comment: If you can't manage roles then you won't be able to assign guild-level permissions. What are you trying to accomplish? Will using the overrides themselves work?

Comment: I tried using overrides as well. Didint work
I made it work by creating  a new role with adminsitration permission and asssigning it to a new user which I used further to manage channels. That worked for my use case